# write permissions in mounted dir to apache user

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, centos6

Sorry for maybe silly/basic question...

I have directory `/var/www/html/logs`. From /var to html `owner:group` is `root:root` and permissions are `drwxr-xr-x`. But "logs" dir has `apache:apache` and `drwxrwxr--`. Webserver in this case is able to write logs [Actually not webserver, but custom function from php]

Another case is `/mnt/d5/logs`

Trying to write there, without success. `/mnt/d5` has `root:root` permissions with `drwxr-xr-x`, hovewer "logs" dir has `apache:apache` with `drwxr-xr-x`, same as the fist case.

My question is, why in first case intermediate rights are not taken in case? Is that related to DocumentRoot of apache config?

What is the best way to resolve current situation? Is giving `0777` rights is the right case?

P.S: Centos 6, no SELinux

=== EDITED ===

```
$logDir = Yii::app()->params['phantomDir'] .....;
$pipeTo = $logDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'script.log';
DirectoryHelper::createDirectory($logDir);
exec('phantomjs ..with its params... > ' . $pipeTo);
...

public static function createDirectory($path, $mode = 0777)
    {
        $oldmask = umask(0);
        if(file_exists($path) == false) {
            mkdir($path, $mode,true);
        }
        umask($oldmask);
    }
```

Comment: /mnt has me thinking about mount, mount options, perhaps mount ro (read-only).

Comment: Yes it's mounted, but script which run from cron from root privileges is able to write

Comment: So, who is running the PHP? What are the current contents of /mnt/d5/logs and what is PHP trying to write?

Comment: Apache is running php. Contents are directories created by scripts. Inside these screenshots[made by phantomjs] and file with log. But these first are should be created by apache

Comment: So, in /mnt/d5/logs there's not a single file or folder created by someone else, no links ...   You're using mod_php, not php-fpm.  The logging would be to a file in /mnt/d5/logs, not a subfolder?  Is it an NFS mount?

Comment: Using mod_php, its ext4 mounted. A logging is to create directory recursively [abs path] and file inside it.

Comment: Can you show the code involved in trying to write a log?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the group permission is the problem? Try out:

```
chmod 775 /mnt/d5/logs
```